# Connection to wireless using terminal, bad driver requests?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, terminal

I'm trying to connect to a networked named "magicmamaliga" but iwconfig isn't letting me.

When running:

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid "magicmamaliga" key "s:PASSWORDXXXXX"
```

and get:

```
Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A) :
Set failed on device wlan0 ; invalid argument
```

I have a feeling it might be how I entered the password/key. The security on the network is WPA2

EDIT: I believe this might be a driver issue. I'm on an eeepc 1002HA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This conversation seems to do the trick](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/656901_).

> `iwconfig ra0 mode managed`
>
> `iwpriv ra0 set AuthMode=WPA2PSK`
>
> `iwpriv ra0 set EncrypType=AES`
>
> `iwconfig ra0 essid "my ESSID"`
>
> `iwpriv ra0 set WPAPSK="my psk ascii passphrase"`
>
> `iwconfig ra0 essid "my ESSID"`

//using WPA2, PSK, AES.

Tell me if that works for you too or if we need to look into more options.

Comment: For some reason whenever I use iwpriv, it says wlan0 no private ioctls